# Michiru is a fake blonde, ok. But what about Sachi and Amane's hair colors?

Tags: tropes, grisaia

Both the VN and the anime stress that Michiru is a fake blonde.

Makina and Yumiko have natural hair colors...

But what about Amane and Sachi? I don't think there are too many natural redheads in the native japanese population of the Kyoto region (where Amane's parents are from), but I am almost sure no human is born with pink hair.

Is this just a case of "[anime hair](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimeHair)", and we are supposed to overlook these two hair colors (MST3k style), or is there something else abou these characters?

What about hair color as a recurring element(as @senshin pointed) in other shows?

Comment: Man, this sort of thing bugs me. The same thing happens in Clannad - Sunohara's blond hair is apparently because he bleached his naturally-black hair, but then you have Kyou/Ryou with purple hair, Kotomi/Tomoya with blue hair, Tomoyo with gray hair...

Comment: @senshin tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimeHair

Comment: Oh, I know, I was more talking about how they choose to explain _some_ of the weird hair colors but not others. Like, we're supposed to look at Sunohara/Michiru and say "wow, that blonde hair looks unusual", but then we come across Kyou/Amane and figure "meh, it's just purple/red hair".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general blonde hair is thought to be foreign in Japan, Most foreign characters/exchange students usually have stereotypically bright blue eyes and blonde hair.

Young people who dye their hair blonde are generally attempts to be 'cool'/rebelious, and are often delinquents. For this reason it is somewhat meaningful that a character has dyed their hair blonde, as it is a thing that happens occasionally in Japan, whereas other colours are not so daring/meaningful.

See [Why are many anime characters blond?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4962/why-are-many-anime-characters-blond/18580#18580)

As for the more 'obscure' shades of hair, pink and other hair colours were originally introduced into anime as an easy way to distinguish characters without adding much more detail.

I haven't watched le fruit de la grisaia, but I imagine that it's probably a result of these two occurrences. I have seen Clannad however , and I can confirm Sunohara's hair is dyed blonde as an attempt to be cool (however misguided that attempt may be :P)