# Nami look-alike in episode 144

Tags: one-piece

In episode 144, around 15:45 of *One Piece*, while salvaging the ship of a navigator that fell from the sky, Sanji came across a picture. The woman in the picture looked almost exactly like Nami.

[image]

It can't be a coincidence because Nami is a prodigy when it comes to navigation, and picture of her look-alike just happen to be at a navigator's ship.

Was that just a coincidence? Is there any theory related to that picture?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is completely related, but Oda kinda draws all the female characters the same (with exception of course) - so maybe that's why you would think the woman looks like Nami.

Comment: if the image i posted is the image you are talking about then i don't see any similarity. Having similar face in anime or manga is common. and check [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22624/6345) out might have some information

Comment: Oda likes to draw older historically significant characters like their modern day counterparts. Showing the parallel between them via similar faces and features. This is shown through the similarities between Zoro and Sword God Ryuma (They are technically related) as well as the similarities between Luffy and Roger at the same age. 
It could just be that since Nami is a prodigy in navigation, she shares a lot of similarities in design with another great navigator at the time. Purely off of the Author's way of designing characters that parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Not confirmed but the popular belief is that the picture reminds Sanji of his mother.

This is a foreshadow of Sanji and his relationship with his mother. It is addressed in the latest arc the Whole Cake Island arc.

Answer (score 1):

This could be Nami's mother because Nami wanted to become a navigator. That means that this trait could be inherited by her mother. And since Nami was a lost child and Oda never mentioned her real father or mother, there could be some mystery going on.

Also, Nami could be another D because her full name hasn't been revealed yet.

Note that this is a theory though.