# When & where did the unnatural hair color aka "You gotta have blue hair trope" originate?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

I specifically want to know which manga or anime started the trend, so I can reason from there to the how question, in order to not make general assumptions.

There was a time in manga/anime where blue hair was abnormal.
For example, from the short clips I've seen of the anime "アタックNo.1", it contains mostly black-haired girls, a couple of brunettes and a sparse blonde. No one there is pink/red/blue-haired. Same with Princess Knight.

Comment: I don't think it's that unusual that you'd want to see colorful hair styles in a country where most people have black hair. Also, manga is monochrome, so only cover page, a rare colored page, or textual description can be used to convey color. Also [this post](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/why-do-many-characters-tend-to-have-crazy-hair-colors-and-styles?rq=1).

Comment: I like a more "This or that anime/manga was the first one to draw anime characters blonde/blue, so drawing a path from here we can start eliminating these assumptions" answer.

Comment: @Hakase All the answers on the question you linked are trying to explain *why* the characters have unnatural hair colors. This question seems to be asking "Can we identify *when* this became part of the anime art style?"

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe from Wild Arms (PSX game). The main hero of WA 1 and WA 2 was blue haired.

Answer (score 1):

Urusei Yatsura had characters with weird hair colors as far back as 1981 and is generally the originator of a lot of things that make anime anime.

But then three years earlier **Uchuu Kaizoku Captain Harlock (1978)** already featured someone with a blue hair color.

That character was an alien, though.

[image: Uchuu Kaizoku Captain Harlock]

Truth be told,... the characters with weird hair colors in Urusei Yatsura were also all aliens.

Similarly, **Kidou Senshi Gundam 0079 (1979)** had characters with blue hair:

[image: M'Quve] [image: Lalah Sune]

Even earlier, **Majokko Meg-chan (1974)**:

[image]
[image]

And I guess the following could also be interesting in general:

[image]

[image]