# Which episode of Sailor Moon is this scene of Usagi in a bath towel from?

Tags: sailor-moon

Which episode of the classic *Sailor Moon* anime are these *douga* (動画) sketches for animation cels of Tsukino Usagi (Sailor Moon) from? I know that in a small number of episodes she was shown with her hair down from its usual [*odango*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/34169/8134) style, but I do not recall an episode in which she was in a bath towel as well as with her hair down straight.

[image: Tsukino Usagi 1]
[image: Tsukino Usagi 2]
[image: Tsukino Usagi 3]
[image: Tsukino Usagi 4]

Answer (score 2):

This was in episode 123 in Sailor Moon S (Super). This is played around the beginning when Chibiusa wonders about Hotaru and Usagi and her are washing up before bedtime.